# windows media encoder 9 insert (link,script) handling

Tags: javascript, asp.net, video-streaming, jscript, windows-media-encoder

hi guys I’m new in broadcasting technology

I’m broadcasting using windows media encoder 9, what I want is while broadcasting when i use insert link option of windows media encoder 9 that time I want to change image path on broadcasting page but when I insert link(of image path) it is redirecting to another page.
 So how to handle inserted link and display it on broadcasting page of client

Broadcasting page is in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

First put `ppt` file and video file in different frames then in `<object>` tag add target frame as `ppt` name. It will work